# Calling the methods in java

Tags: java

I know what it is the **Calling the  methods in java** and before the question, I read  about Java grammar very much.I know what it is the **this** in java, but I do not know, How is invoked the following code in **MainActivity. java**

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(120,120,40,paint);
}
```

Now. I put the full code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Draw draw;
    Cal cal;
    TextView textView;
    RelativeLayout linearLayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        super.onCreate(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.t);
        cal = new Cal(this);
        cal.cal();

        textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText("" + cal.result);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        draw = new Draw(this);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        linearLayout.addView(draw);
    }
}
```

**Cal.java**

```
public class Cal extends View {
    Cal(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public double result;
    double parameter = (Math.pow(40,2)) * 3.14;
    public void cal(){
        result = Math.sqrt(parameter);

    }
}
```

**Draw.java**

```
public class Draw extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
    Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(120,120,40,paint);
    }
}
```

The     `public void cal(){ result = Math.sqrt(parameter);`} is invoked by  `cal.cal();` **in MainActivity** But I do not know, How is invoked the

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(120,120,40,paint);
}
```

in **MainActivity.java** ??
in **MainActivity.java**, we have only the  `draw = new Draw(this);` for calling the `Draw(Context context) {super(context);}`  in **Draw.java**

Comment: I dont understand what your question is, please can you explain further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Draw class extends the android class View.

You are adding a view to your layout in the onCreateMethod():

```
linearLayout.addView(draw);
```

Android will call the onDraw() method in the draw object when the view is rendering.

Comment: Thank you. Cal. java also extends the android class View. then, why we should use "cal.cal();" for calling the call() method?

Comment: Because your Draw class is overriding a method of the View class: 'public void onDraw(Canvas c)'. In your class 'Cal' the method 'cal()' is a method of your class and you need to call this method yourself.