# Once using the override method and once more using without the override method and two different result

Tags: java

The answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202370/calling-the-methods-in-java) was useful for me. But I have a new question about that. I read the Java grammar but I have problems in some part of the Java grammar and for this reason, I ask my questions here. I changed two part of the code link as the following:

**In Draw.java:**
I changed the `public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)` To the `public void d(Canvas canvas)`

And I added the following in **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Draw draw;
    Cal cal;
    TextView textView;
    RelativeLayout linearLayout;   

    Canvas canvas;

    public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        super.onCreate(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.t);
        cal = new Cal(this);
        cal.cal();

        textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText("" + cal.result);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        draw = new Draw(this);            

        draw.d(canvas);

        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        linearLayout.addView(draw);
    }}
```

the code can compile and install successfully.But only it can run for a short time in my device and also it can not run in **AVD** manager.
I'm sure the grammar used is correct.But I do not know what is the cause of the collision in the code that I can not see the output Code correctly.

**UPDATE, Draw.java**

```
public class Draw extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public void d(Canvas canvas) {
  paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(120,120,40,paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post Draw class as well?

Comment: I added the Draw class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't try it, maybe it's stupid but try to add public front of the Draw constructor:

```
**public** Draw(Context context) {
     super(context);
}
```

And in d() method, there should be one less parenthesis.